# ¿Qué es un dativo? ¿Cuántos hay? ¿Cuál es su diferencia con los pronombres reflexivos?

Tags: pronombres, verbo-pronominal

He visto ejemplos donde frases como "me viene la película" o "no se lo digas a nadie" tienen el pronombre "se" como dativo, lo que no entiendo es qué diferencia a un dativo de un reflexivo.

Comment: La primera frase de ejemplo no tiene un "se". ¿Es un error?

Comment: Pues, estaba considerando , "me, te, se.." como dativos o reflexivos.

Comment: En ese caso puedes ampliar un poco la pregunta especificando eso, y explicarnos un poco cuál es tu conocimiento actual del tema: cuanto más concretes la duda mejor podremos ayudarte. ¡Y bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En gramática se le llama **dativo** por tradición (el caso dativo del latín) a lo que expresa un objeto indirecto. Por ejemplo, en *"No se lo digas a nadie"* el pronombre de tercera persona *se* es dativo (parte del objeto indirecto). En este caso *se* y *a nadie* son los dos el mismo objeto indirecto, pero por una regla gramatical del castellano, *se* tiene que aparecer aunque sea redundante. Otros ejemplos de pronombres dativos (en **negrita**):

- ***Les*** dimos regalos.
- *Debo entregar**le** esta carta.*
- ***Se*** lo vamos a decir.

(El pronombre dativo normalmente es *le* o *les*; cuando hay un pronombre de objeto directo, o acusativo, el dativo cambia a *se*.)

Un **pronombre reflexivo** es un pronombre de objeto que refiere al mismo sujeto. Los pronombres reflexivos de primera y segunda persona son iguales a los de objeto (*me*, *te*, *nos*, *os*), pero el pronombre reflexivo de tercera persona es *se* (en singular o plural).

En estos ejemplos *se* es acusativo (objeto directo):

- *Se miró en el espejo.*
- *Se perdieron en la selva.*

En estos *se* es dativo (objeto indirecto):

- *Se compró un regalo.*
- *Se hizo daño.*

Comment: También existe el dativo ético, que no me parece representado en tus ejemplos.